# User authentication error using express not working

Tags: express, authentication, jwt, bcrypt

So I'm having trouble authenticating a user login using express for the backend. If I do a simple res.send   I could get a response in postman. but if I do a check if the user and password check and generate a token if says error 401 invalid usernames and password. mind the tokens work for register and update profiles. I also attached the user schema.
Simple Approach

```
const authUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body
  res.send({ email, password })
})
```

[image]

When I try to check and generate a token

```
const authUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body
  const user = await User.findOne({ email })

  if (user && (await user.matchPassword(password))) {
    res.json({
      _id: user._id,
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email,
      isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
      token: generateToken(user._id),
    })
  } else {
    res.status(401)
    throw new Error('Invalid Email or password')
  }
})
```

[image]

Also here's my user schema using mongoose and added a function to check password since in the database it's encrypted using bcrypt.js

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs'

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    isAdmin: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
)

userSchema.methods.matchPassword = async function (enteredPassword) {
  return await bcrypt.compare(enteredPassword, this.password)
}

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)

export default User
```

Answer (score 0):

You see, your code is absolutely correct, but only if you have saved the user correctly in your model at the first. In addition, the password used during storage is hashed in the same way and from the same module.

Now you have to change your checking terms because there may not really be a user with this email in the database to match your password and return true value.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs'

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    isAdmin: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
)

userSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  if (this.password) {
        bcrypt.hash(this.password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(15), (err, hash) => {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            this.password = hash;
            next();
        });
    }
}

userSchema.methods.Save = async (data) => {
    let model=new User(data)
    await model.save();
}

userSchema.methods.matchPassword = async function (enteredPassword) {
  return await bcrypt.compare(enteredPassword, this.password)
}

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)

export default User
```

and update this code:

```
const authUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body
  const user = await User.findOne({ email })

  if (user) {
    if(await user.matchPassword(password)) {
      res.json({
        _id: user._id,
        name: user.name,
        email: user.email,
        isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
        token: generateToken(user._id),
      })
    } else {
      res.status(401)
      throw new Error('Invalid password')
    }
  } else {
    res.status(401)
    throw new Error('Invalid Email')
  }
})
```

Now you know which part of the job is the problem. No user or no wrist password